# How to load media's album cover with glide?

Tags: android, kotlin, view, android-glide

So I have songList[position].id as my MediaStore ID. I tried below method to read from albumart but it didn't work.

```
val artworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart")
        val path = ContentUris.withAppendedId(artworkUri, songList[position].id)
        Glide.with(holder.songCover.context).load(songList[position].path.toUri()).into(holder.songCover)
```

I also tried `Glide.with(holder.songCover.context).loadFromMediaStore()`, but it seems that this method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have the necessary permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and get permissions in your app

use this :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

then  modify your code as follows:

```
 val artworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart")
val albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(artworkUri, songList[position].id)
Glide.with(holder.songCover.context)
     .load(albumArtUri)
     .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) // Optional placeholder image while loading
     .error(R.drawable.error) // Optional error image if loading fails
     .into(holder.songCover)
```

Comment: Thanks! But how to catch the errors from glide correctly (in case that the music I'm reading doesn't include an albumart) ? Even if I have set a placeholder and an error image the log would still spam my logcat...